# A summation involving the ceiling function

Tags: algorithms, summation, computational-mathematics

I'm trying to find a better method of calculating the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^N\lceil ak\rceil^2$$

where $a$ is an irrational number.  So far, my only idea is to somehow use [a best rational approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations).  I believe I should be able to calculate at the very least

$$\sum_{k=1}^d\lceil\frac{ck}d\rceil^2$$

where $c$ and $d$ are integers.  However, that will leave several values at the end and, in this case, a linear algorithm won't do.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the last summation goes to $d$ and not to $N$ ?

Comment: In what form is the irrational number $a$ given? As a continued fraction, as a algebraic number, as an infinite string of digits?

Comment: @pew I was trying to keep this as abstract as possible, but for my purposes, it's the multiplicative inverse of the golden ratio.  For example, if $N$ were $100$, I would use the approximation $\frac{55}{89}$.  I'll try to verify I can perform the sum from 1 to 89 on paper, but that will still leave the last 11 values.  Let's just say the actual value of $N$ I need to deal with is quite a bit larger than $100$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The $d$ was intentional, but it appears I can't quite figure that sum out either.  I figured if $\frac cd$ were a reduced fraction, the fractional part of $\frac{ck}d$ would take on each value from $\frac1d$ to $\frac{d-1}{d}$ once.  However, that squaring presents a troublesome middle term...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It makes things clearer to me (I am very bad in this area as well as in many other). Cheers :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to also include the specific question. Generalization could make the problem harder, and you might not get any answer. Also, please mention the source/motivation/context if possible. Is this is some puzzle given to you? Did you come across it during your research etc...

Comment: @Aryabhata An update will be coming, perhaps later in the day.  I'll say for now that this is more or less what's left of a Project Euler problem (one in the 300s) boiled down as far as I could get it.  I try to give away as little as possible and do as much as possible.  However, I might have made the problem harder by not including the entire summation.  It may get around that problem with the middle term I mentioned in an earlier comment.  I have more work to do first.

Comment: @Mike: Don't you think that is a bit unfair to people who might be trying to solve the general problem (which might be too hard)? Perhaps the specific problem has an easier solution? (In fact, I know that for certain specific irrationals we can give fast algorithms).

Comment: @Aryabhata Some people are concerned about fastest times for the most recent problems.  As there are almost 500 problems currently, this is not among them.  Add that research is encouraged and that the problem has been boiled down quite a bit already and I'm fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I have posted this question before and got a couple of answers to it, however, because of the wrong wording, it was not what I was really looking for. Currently, I am trying repost my question, but it continuously gets closed mentioning “you have already posted that question”. Could you help me solve this problem? Thanks!

This is my problem. Let b be binary string of length r<n, b doesn’t contain any adjacent 0's or 1's. Count number of binary string of length n that if we repeatedly apply these operations 1) 11=1, 2)00=0 we will get string b.
b doesn’t contain adjacent 0's or 1's. For example r=2,n=3,b=01 The strings that result b after those operations are 001, and 011
so the answer is 2.

Comment: You are going about this in a counter-productive way.  Attempting an *end run* around MathSE protocols will probably not succeed.  See the following series of comments.  They will help you to work within the system, to get your question answered.

Comment: First of all, see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.   ...see next comment

Comment: For what it's worth, any posting that makes a **serious** effort to provide all requested details, in a very organized / well written manner, with respect to the previous comment, will go a long way towards **positively influencing** MathSE reviewers.   ...see next comment

Comment: Under similar circumstances, if you had posted a question, received an answer, and then wanted to post a related follow-up question, then I would suggest posting a new question, with the new question providing a link to the old question.  **This is not the situation that you are presently in.**  ...see next comment

Comment: Given the situation, as you describe it, your *end-around* attempts have dug you into a hole.  I strongly suggest the following: go to the most recent posting that you created, on this question.  Presumably, this posting is now closed.  **Very carefully**, edit this posting to provide all the requested details, re the protocol article that I linked you to.  **Also,** very carefully explain, (perhaps somewhat in **bold letters**), why that you feel that your **edited** question has not yet been answered.   ...see next comment

Comment: That is, your are explaining why it is not a *duplicate question*.  One of the **failings** of MathSE reviewers, is that they are sometimes too quick to mislabel a question as a duplicate.  By editing the **closed** question, you are following the MathSE protocol of attempting to get the closed question re-opened.  This is the procedure that MathSE reviewers **want you to follow**. ...see next comment

Comment: **Only after** you have completed the very careful editing of the closed question, leave a comment here, following this comment.  Address the comment to @user2661923.  This will **flag** me.  In the flagging comment, provide a link to the closed question that you have **just edited**.  I will personally review the edited posting.  **If** you have followed my instructions, and the posting is now of high quality, then I will vote to re-open the question and I will **also lobby** for others to vote to re-open the question.  If and when the question is re-opened, then things can proceed normally.

Comment: After leaving the previous comments, I reviewed the question that you presented in the **answer** box.  I found it somewhat unclear, and I imagine other MathSE reviewers will also find it unclear.  So, one of my suggested improvements is that you completely overhaul your presentation of the question.  You want to use judicious line breaks (via `<br>`) and paragraph breaks.  You also want to present the Math via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  ...see next comment

Comment: Further, I recommend that you strive to make it crystal clear what you are asking.  Your goal (perhaps unattainable) should be to try and make it all but impossible for anyone to be confused as to what you are asking.  This means that after very carefully describing the problem, you provide $4$ or $5$ examples that illustrate the ideas that you are trying to communicate.  The last thing that you want to do is frustrate the MathSE reviewers who are examining your posting.  The easier that you make their life, the more inclined that they will be to answer the question.

Comment: As an example of following the protocol, see [this posted question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673292/complex-analysis-topology-problem).  The only thing missing from this posting was that I forgot to give a detailed description of my Math education.  The underlying question was a reasonable one, **but nothing great**.  The high score was the result of other MathSE reviewers appreciating the effort that I made to follow the protocol.